# cmd "Error: Could not find or load main class" error

Tags: java, cmd

I've read through the other questions and have tried googling the solutions, but I couldn't find the solution I was looking for.

This program compiles and runs on NetBeans, but only complies on CMD.  I WANT to get it running with CMD.

[image: cmd window]

[image: program.java file]

I'm not very good with Java - just starting out and this is a uni project.

Comment: Please, use IDE to write and launch programs.

Answer (score 2):

The program is in a package `chess`. Move up a folder,

```
C:\Users\Nihir\Documents\chess> cd ..\
C:\Users\Nihir\Documents> java -cp . chess.Program
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use fully qualified names to invoke a class from the commandline. which would be "chess.Program" instead of "Program"

Answer (score 0):

First of all return back to your program directory

```
cd..
```

Now simply give the command

```
java Program
```